# Error in creating controller using artisan - laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Im trying to create a controller using this command: `php artisan controller:make CupcakesController` but i am receiving this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "type": "ErrorException",
        "message": "include(\/opt\/lampp\/htdocs\/cupcakes-lara\/app\/controllers\/CupcakesController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory",
        "file": "\/opt\/lampp\/htdocs\/cupcakes-lara\/vendor\/composer\/ClassLoader.php",
        "line": 185
    }
}
```

whats wrong with this?

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFO: I can successfully run migrate commands in artisan right now

Comment: Your directories, specifically the *controllers* directory, it is writable? Trying changing the permissions.

Comment: I already did it and still the same error.

Answer (score 3):

This error is generated if you create a route that points to a non-existent controller in routes.php and then try to make the controller using Artisan. Comment out the route and try again :)

Answer (score 0):

That's [generator](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Generator#controllers), not artisan?

```
php artisan generate:controller CupcakesController
```

Comment: php artisan controller:make CupcakesController is the right command to create a controller artisan way. What is the reason that makes you offer this command? I couldn't understand.

Comment: If you follow the link I provided, you'll be reading the specific documentation for the generator package which provides this functionality.  It's terrific. Much more than just generate:controller.  Also try this [Artisan Commands](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/your-one-stop-guide-to-laravel-commands/) - btw, where did you see that php artisan:make CupcakesController ?  IMO, it is not correct.

Comment: I saw it in my terminal. When i write it, i can generate a new controller. But when I write generate:controller; I can't. Wierd by the way...

Comment: I found it in laravel 4 offline documentation. Refering to page 41, Resource Controllers: To create the controller via the command line, execute the following command:
1
php artisan controller:make PhotoController

Comment: There are 2 sets of laravel docs... four.laravel.com the "beta" docs.  There is some different and useful information there, but

Comment: sorry, i began to write a long reply and got sidetracked. Just for clarity, here is the link to the current docs: [http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) Anyway, I tested this on a clean install, and now it worked for me. Sorry :) I still recommend checking out that generator package- good luck